# GET request with basic auth working in Postman, but getting 403 when getting it with OkHttp

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp

I'm using OkHttp with Kotlin in Android to query a REST API using basic auth.
When I use Postman to GET the resource I get:

- 200 when using basic auth -> So my credentials are correct and working
- 401 without using basic auth -> Expected behaviour (Unauthorized)

But **when I use OkHttp I always get 403** with both preemptive and reactive authentication or even if I don't add any auth header at all.

Here's what I tried so far:

1. Adding **"Authorization" header** to request
2. Adding an **Interceptor** to client adding auth header to all requests
3. Adding an **Authenticator** to client
4. I only found this issue to be of any relevance, but I already use **https instead of http** in the URI. (Using http doesn't work either.)

My code to send the GET request:

```
    private val client = OkHttpClient().newBuilder().build()

    fun getOrders() {
        val credentials = Credentials.basic(/*username*/, /*password*/)
        val request = Request.Builder()
            .url("https://example.com")
            .addHeader("Authorization", credentials)
            .build()

        // Shows that request actually contains the header so that's OK
        request.headers.forEach { println(it) }

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                println("Response STATUS: " + response.code)
            }
        })
    }
```

I think I ruled out the problem being on the server's end with Postman handling all this correctly and I don't have any other idea what might work.

Comment: You would need to talk to your server team to confirm what a 403 means with respect to the particular URL that you are requesting. That is supposed to mean that you do not have rights to the resource. You might also consider adding the logging interceptor to your `OkHttpClient`, so you can see in Logcat exactly what you are sending. To me, the fact that you are getting 200 or 401 in Postman, but 403 with OkHttp, suggests that there is a discrepancy in the URL more than in the authentication.

Comment: You can log request body by adding interceptor like: `HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply { level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY }`

Comment: @CommonsWare I query the same URL using both Postman and OkHttp. Thanks for your input though. I'll try to pull up some logs on the server to get more info.